# I'm trying to get the two buttons to fill the width of the Template. How would I do this

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, css, html

I want it to look like each tab is 50% of the template.
[image]

```
<template>
    <lightning-tabset variant="scoped" active-tab-value="2">
        <template class="slds-grid slds-gutters" for:each={tabs} for:item="tab">
            <lightning-tab class="slds-col" label={tab.label} key={tab.value} value={tab.value} onactive={handleActive}>
                {tab.content}
            </lightning-tab>
        </template>
    </lightning-tabset>
    <!--lightning-formatted-text value={activeValueMessage} ></lightning-formatted-text-->
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

    const NUM_OF_TABS = 2;
    
    export default class masteriesAndFeats extends LightningElement {
        activeValueMessage = '';
    
        get tabs() {
            const tabs = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < NUM_OF_TABS; i++) {
                if(i == 0){
                    tabs.push({
                        value: `${i}`,
                        label: 'Masteries',
                    });
                }else{
                    tabs.push({
                        value: `${i}`,
                        label: 'Feats',
                    });
                }
            }
            return tabs;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see no buttons here. Are you talking about the tabs?

Comment: Yes, it supposed to be tabs, not buttons sorry.